# Para que serve default(object) em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sintaxe

Às vezes me deparo com a palavra-chave `default` no C#:

```
object obj = default(object);
string str = default(string);
int number = default(int);
```

- Para que serve?
- Em qual cenário eu posso aplicar isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nesse exemplo não parece ser necessário. Isso é o mesmo que:

```
object obj = null;
```

O `default` gera o valor padrão de um tipo, no caso de tipos por referência o valor padrão é um nulo.

O mesmo vale para `string` que é um tipo por referência.

Mas para o `int` o valor padrão é o 0. Tem que consultar os tipos por valor qual é o valor padrão adotado, quase sempre é 0, mas há alguns casos que o 0 não faz sentido, então pode ser outro valor. Portanto para `int` sabemos que é o mesmo que:

```
int number = 0;
```

Já é esquisito criar um objeto do tipo `object`, isso raramente é necessário e quase sempre por causa de algum legado. Esse tipo não tem conteúdo, então é um objeto sem valor, algo que concretamente não faz muito sentido. Ele poderia ser um *placeholder* para um outro tipo real, mas se isso é necessário deveria usar um tipo genérico e não `object`.

Fica mais esquisito ainda quando você sabe o tipo que está tentando criar o valor padrão. O mais comum é usar isso com tipos genéricos, onde não sabe qual deve ser o valor padrão. Mesmo assim em alguns casos nem é necessário. Isso faria algum sentido:

```
var obj = default(T);
```

Considerando que `T` é um *placeholder* para o tipo real. Esse é um caso que faz muito sentido, principalmente se puder ter tipos por valor.

Em alguns casos onde há aplicação de *pattern matching* também pode ser útil.

Sem um cenário genérico ou *pattern matching* é difícil justificar o uso. Pode se dizer que é para deixar mais claro que é o valor padrão, mas aí começa entrar em gosto, não ajuda muito de fato. Se você sabe qual é o tipo, sabe seu valor padrão e ele não pode mudar em condições normais, então não tem porque usar nesse cenário, só quando o tipo será definido mais tarde.

Em tese em um tipo por valor criado por alguém o valor padrão poderia mudar ao longo do tempo de vida da solução e esse é um caso que ele seria útil mesmo sabendo qual é o tipo específico, porém há algo muito errado com um tipo que começa com um valor padrão e depois muda, provavelmente quebrará alguns códigos ou porque não usaram `default`, ou porque usaram mas esperavam um valor estável. Não faça isso.

Se o tipo foi especificado ele não precisa ser especificado novamente, algo assim é normal:

```
T obj = default;
int number = default;
```

Se o mecanismo de referências anuláveis estiver ligado e acho que hoje deve sempre trabalhar assim o uso do `default` fica muito esquisito porque ele seria o mesmo que:

```
string str = null;
```

Acontece que nesse modo `str` não aceita nulo, não faz sentido. Isto faria sentido:

```
string? str = default;
```

porque assim o nulo é um valor aceitável, mas em `string` não é, então já inicializa errado. É só mais um motivo para não usar quando se sabe o tipo que está usando. O mais comum seria usar algo como:

```
string str = "";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/Default.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Nesse caso em especifico é o operador [padrão](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-operator) ou [literal](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal) que produz um valor padrão de um determinado tipo, exemplo o valor padrão de um `int` é o número 0, o valor padrão o literal de um `DateTime` é `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` e assim por diante, cada tipo de dado na linguagem C# tem o seu valor inicial ou padrão.

O valor de um dado complexo, classe e `String` (que também é uma classe) é `null`.

Há duas formas de declarar o valor padrão que é com argumento do tipo em especifico, **exemplo**:

```
int i = default(int);
```

e a outra forma desde a versão 7.1 é literal que não precisa passar nenhum argumento, deixando a responsabilidade com o compilador possa inferir o tipo da expressão, **exemplo**:

```
int i = default;
```

Pode ser utilizado quando for necessário ter um valor padrão em alguma variável, depende do seu código, contexto que isso seja útil, geralmente utilizado para argumentos. Como declarado pela própria documentação:

- Na atribuição ou inicialização de uma variável.
- Na declaração do valor padrão para um parâmetro de [método opcional](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/methods#optional-parameters-and-arguments).
- Em uma chamada de método para fornecer um valor de argumento.
- Em uma [return instrução](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return) ou como uma expressão em um membro [expression-apto para](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal).

---

<sup>***ref.*** [*https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal*](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal)</sup>

<sup>***Referencia***</sup>

- [default (Referência de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default)
- [expressões de valor padrão (referência C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default)